# Encountered a Data Table Error when running my MVC Web App in an IE Browser

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

As I run the project I get this error sent back to me.

Unhandled exception at line 257, column 1 in
http://localhost:54123/Scripts/Custom/custom-validation.js

0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'DataTable'

And below is the part of the code it's referring to..

```
$('.dtable-fd').DataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [{
        'bSortable': false,
        'aTargets': [0,1]
    }],
});
```

The project works fine when running on a Chrome Browser, but encounters this error when running it on an Internet Explorer Browser. What should I do?

Comment: have you checked your web.config file?

Comment: Bear with me on this, but what should I do with it?
I'm really new to this MVC thing.

Comment: Can you post the table code from the View, and also the script files that are included?

Answer (score 0):

DataTable are supported in IE. Check your HTML code, has any tag not closed. Check this link, it might help you
[It solved similar problem I guess](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/14234/datatables-specific-jquery-not-working-in-internet-explorer-8-solved)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But sadly it still didn't fix the problem.